# Scraping text of class with Selenium and with whitespaces between different text parts

Tags: python, selenium

I want to **scrape** with Selenium all text values of the class "tore-dots" from this website: https://www.fussballdaten.de/vereine/fc-bayern-muenchen/2019/

Therefore I use the following function:

```
dots_graph = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tore-dots")
dots_graph.text
```

The Result is one concatenated string like: '612119891210117968576554353345443434333'

However, the numbers stand for different placements and have a maximum of two digits.
How can I scrape the text with a separator symbol. E.g. all different elements separated in a list instead of concatenated in a string?

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Please include a [repro].

Comment: Thank you, I edit my post, so you can better understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `driver.execute_script` to get the text values:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.fussballdaten.de/vereine/fc-bayern-muenchen/2019/')
dot_vals = d.execute_script('return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("g.tore-dots text")).map(x => x.innerHTML)')
```

Output:

```
['2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '6', '4', '2', '3', '5', '5', '4', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

After getting `dots_graph` you should use `dots_graph.find_elements_...` (with char `s` in word `elements`) to search all `<text>` inside `dots_graph` as separated elements, and then you should use `for`-loop to get `.text` from every `<text>`

```
dots_graph = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tore-dots")

all_items = dots_graph.find_elements_by_tag_name("text")

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
```

Or you could try to get `tore-dots` and `<text>` in one `xpath`

```
# doesn't work with `g` and `text` - maybe because it is inside `<SVG>` 
#all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g[@class="tore-dots"]//text')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="tore-dots"]//*[name()="text"]')

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
```

or the same with `CSS` selector

```
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tore-dots text')

for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
```

---

**BTW:** `.text` doesn't means `<text>` like it can means in `beautifulsoup`

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
from selenium import webdriver

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.fussballdaten.de/vereine/fc-bayern-muenchen/2019/')

# close popup window with message
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Einwilligen"]').click()

print('--- FIND ---')

dots_graph = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tore-dots")
all_items = dots_graph.find_elements_by_tag_name("text")

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
print(dot_vals)

print('--- XPATH (g, text) ---')

# doesn't work with `g` and `text` - maybe because it is inside `<SVG>` 
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//g[@class="tore-dots"]//text')  

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
print(dot_vals)

print('--- XPATH (*, name) ---')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="tore-dots"]//*[local-name()="text"]')

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
print(dot_vals)

print('--- XPATH (*, local-name) ---')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="tore-dots"]//*[name()="text"]')

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
print(dot_vals)

print('--- CSS ---')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tore-dots text')

dot_vals = [item.text for item in all_items]
print(dot_vals)
```